# ETL package integration with Oracle Apex for CSV upload feature?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating a CSV upload feature on APEX with an ETL package integration. I am unsure where I am able to call the package once I click ‘Upload File’. The following happens through the package.

- Apex to load CSV with partner id, file_id based on new table (td_file_upload)
- Apex to distinguish if user uploading is partner org user or admin user on behalf of partner.
- Apex to call ETL package .
- Database will check for first_name, last_name and one of email not null (mandatory check)
- Database will check for valid email at least for one of the emails.
- The above two pass will result in profile entry in td_profile.
- Database will proceed with rest of other attribute loading. If any error then it will be recorded in a  table and  row will be marked ‘E” though profile created.
- Apex will update flag for reprocessing as R based on data correction.
- Database will pick R & N status record and insert/update based on previously profile created.
- Successful profile create and attributes load will be marked as status=Processed.
- Any duplicate email match found then row will be marked as D=duplicate as profile already created by other user/partner.

How can I integrate this ETL package with the CSV file uploader?

Comment: Check the package APEX_DATA_PARSER.  This [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex-data-parser-package) explains a similar scenario to what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck in this sort of thing by loading the CSV to a temporary table, then processing the results and saving them to my target table.

Hopefully that'll work for you